# Complete second part of row by clicking a button?

Tags: vb.net, button, datagrid, datagridview

I have a screen containing two button and a datagrid with 6 columns. When button 1 pressed, it displays data in a row for columns 1 through 4. When I press button 2, I want my application to populate the remaining columns in the row (ie column 5 and 6).

The solution may be obvious, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

**Edit:** Sorry I forgot to mention before, when I click the second button, the data appears in the correct position ie in the last two columns. Except it's not on the same row. The data appears one row down.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub btnClockIn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClockIn.Click

Homescreen.DataGridViewEmployee.ColumnCount = 6
Homescreen.DataGridViewEmployee.Columns(0).Name = "Employee Number"
Homescreen.DataGridViewEmployee.Columns(1).Name = "Day"
Homescreen.DataGridViewEmployee.Columns(2).Name = "Week Number"
Homescreen.DataGridViewEmployee.Columns(3).Name = "Time In"
Homescreen.DataGridViewEmployee.Columns(4).Name = "Time Out"
Homescreen.DataGridViewEmployee.Columns(5).Name = "Hours"

Dim row As String() = New String() {ENumber, day, WeekNum, StartTime, "", ""}
Homescreen.DataGridViewEmployee.Rows.Add(row)
Homescreen.DataGridViewEmployee.ReadOnly = True

Private Sub btnClockOut_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClockOut.Click

Homescreen.DataGridViewEmployee.ColumnCount = 6
Homescreen.DataGridViewEmployee.Columns(0).Name = "Employee Number"
Homescreen.DataGridViewEmployee.Columns(1).Name = "Day"
Homescreen.DataGridViewEmployee.Columns(2).Name = "Week Number"
Homescreen.DataGridViewEmployee.Columns(3).Name = "Time In"
Homescreen.DataGridViewEmployee.Columns(4).Name = "Time Out"
Homescreen.DataGridViewEmployee.Columns(5).Name = "Hours"

Dim row As String() = New String() {"", "", "", "", EndTime, Diff}
Homescreen.DataGridViewEmployee.Rows.Add(row)
Homescreen.DataGridViewEmployee.ReadOnly = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the second button you are using the `rows.add()` method which as it is named adds to a row. if you want to add to the last row you need to get the last row using `rows(rows.Count -1)` then edit the relevant fields in the list

```
Dim row as DataGridViewRow = rows(rows.Count -1)
row(4) = EndTime
row(5) = Diff
```

It is unnecessary to set the properties of the data grid view with every button press so all the code about Column names can be removed, as can the readonly setting.